# Installing into parent path not allowed when installing locally built Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I've written a Ruby gem that I'd like to install locally. I'm using Rubygems 3.0.6 and RVM on OS X Mojave. This is a closed source gem and I'd rather not go to the trouble of publishing it to the company gemservers. I'm able to install other (published) gems just fine using both `bundle install` and `gem install`.

The gem is all built (using `gem build`) and the code works, but when I run:

```
gem install influx_trello_utility-0.1.0.gem
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::PathError)
    installing into parent path /bin/[ of /Users/danascheider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@influx_trello_utility/gems/influx_trello_utility-0.1.0 is not allowed
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: May be premission issue, please run chmod to the path and install gem again.

Comment: @fidato The `gem install` command would run as my user, correct? That's the same user that owns that path. Was that what you were suggesting I change, or am I missing something?

Comment: You may run `chmod -R 777 /Users/danascheider/.rvm/gems` and execute it again.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't do it.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not that I recall, I think I had to find a workaround.